# Object Copying. What's the difference?

Tags: php, object, clone

In the below example .. I have some confusion down here

```
<?php
class SubObject
{
    static $instances = 0;
    public $instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->instance = ++self::$instances;
    }

}

class MyCloneable
{
    public $object1;
    public $object2;

    function __clone()
    {
        $this->object1 = clone $this->object1;
        $this->object2 = clone $this->object2;
    }
}

$obj = new MyCloneable();

$obj->object1 = new SubObject();
$obj->object2 = new SubObject();

$obj2 = clone $obj;//If i use $obj2 = $obj; it does return the same results.

print("Original Object:\n");
print_r($obj);

print("Cloned Object:\n");
print_r($obj2);
```

What is the difference between in doing `$obj2 = clone $obj;` and `$obj2 = $obj;` ? Both does return the same results. So why should I use `clone` keyword ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$obj2 = clone $obj
var_dump($obj === $obj2); // bool(false)
```

It creates a new `MyCloneable` instance based on `$obj` and stores it into `$obj2`.
**Each variable contains an instance of `MyCloneable`.**

---

```
$obj2 = $obj
var_dump($obj === $obj2); // bool(true)
```

The above statement assigns `$obj` into `$obj2`.
**These two variables are the same instance.**